# When is matplotlib's pyplot.figure redundant?

Tags: python, matplotlib

From my understanding of `matplotlib`, the `figure` method creates a new, blank figure, basically a "white canvas," and via, for example, `plot` I can add the actual plot. The `show` method then clears the `figure`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

1) Now, I am wondering why the same can be achieved when no `figure` was created. More specifically, I am wondering how `matplotlib` handles this internally.

2) Is there any advantage in using `plt.figure` if I don't intend to manipulate figure objects?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `plt.plot` internally [calls `gca`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L3126) (get current axes) which then [calls `gcf`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L917) (get current figure), which returns the current (last used) figure. If there is no current figure it [calls `plt.figure`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L561) and returns the newly created figure. So yes, weather or not you call `plt.figure` yourself doesn't really matter. I wouldn't say it is redundant (since it has to be done), but you can safely let matplotlib take care of it.
2. Directly calling `plt.figure` if you don't intend to manipulate the figure or pass arguments to the constructor is only useful to create multiple figures to show them simultaneously when calling `plt.show`.

   ```
   plt.figure()
   plt.plot(1,1,'x')
   plt.figure()
   plt.plot(2,2,'o')
   plt.show()
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice explanation, makes sense now!